# SQL convert dates to weekday name

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm working in SQL Server and I have a table like so;

[image: My Table]

What I am trying to achieve; I am trying to collate a list of the most frequent days off sick. I need to convert the [Sick Leave Start Date] column to a day of the week. I have no problem achieving this using `DATENAME(day, GETDATE())`.

This works for getting the day of the week the user first went sick - however where [Total Days Off] is greater than 1, I need to iterate through each date and store the day name.

So I am looking to achieve something like the below;

[image: desired results]

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? Also, Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, the relevant RDBMS tag (product and product+version), your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: did u tried with row_number function can u explain your expected output please in columns

Comment: Try using DATEADD() to add the number of sick days minus 1 (need to count the sickleavestartdate as one day) to the SickLeaveStartDate, then do your DateName() call

Comment: @Mark Do you want to have every day of the week a person was sick for records where total days is greater than 1, or just the day of the week for the last day of sick leave when days off is greater than 1?

Comment: Hi @RyanWilson - I am looking for everyday. The first, the last and everything in between. Sorry if that wasn't very clear

Comment: @Mark no problem, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You *don't* need to iterate. You can't use `DATENAME` for this anyway. You should use a Calendar table, preferabley one that contains day names (eg WeekDay),  and join your table with it on the condition that the calendar's date is between `Start Date` and `dateadd(d,DaysOff,StartDate)` After that all you need to do is group by WeekDay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First generate your sickness date ranges, then join with a calendar table (I generate one recursivelly here) and group by the name of each day.

```
;WITH RecursiveCalendar AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = CONVERT(DATE, '2018-01-01')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.GeneratedDate)
    FROM
        RecursiveCalendar AS C
    WHERE
        C.GeneratedDate < '2019-01-01'
),
SickRanges AS
(
    SELECT
        S.StartDate,
        EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, CEILING(S.DaysOff) - 1, S.StartDate)
    FROM
        YourTable AS S
)
SELECT
    Weekday = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, C.GeneratedDate),
    AmountSickDays = COUNT(1)
FROM
    SickRanges AS R
    INNER JOIN RecursiveCalendar AS C ON C.GeneratedDate BETWEEN R.StartDate AND R.EndDate
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, C.GeneratedDate)
ORDER BY
    COUNT(1) DESC
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 30000)
```

Replace your table and column on the 2nd CTE to run.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_DAYS_SICK') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp_DAYS_SICK
  CREATE TABLE #TEMP_DAYS_SICK
  (
  DAYWEEK VARCHAR(25)
  )
  DECLARE @DATE DATE,@TARGETDATE DATE,@OFFSET INT
  SET @OFFSET = 25
  SET @DATE = GETDATE()
  SET @TARGETDATE = DATEADD(DD,@OFFSET,@DATE)
  WHILE(@DATE <> @TARGETDATE)
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #TEMP_DAYS_SICK
  SELECT DATENAME(DW,@DATE)
  SET @DATE = DATEADD(DD,1,@DATE)
  END

  SELECT DAYWEEK,COUNT(1) AS DAYS_SICK FROM #TEMP_DAYS_SICK GROUP BY DAYWEEK
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to get the name of the day where the total days off is greater than 1.
Try this...

```
select DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(day, TotalDaysOff, SickLeaveStartDate)) as SickDay 
from [table_name] where 
TotalDaysOff > 1
```

For Mark, this might suffice:

```
select DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(day, TotalDaysOff, SickLeaveStartDate)) + ', ' + 
DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(day, (TotalDaysOff-1), SickLeaveStartDate)) as SickDay 
from [table_name] where 
TotalDaysOff > 1
```

However, you might want to put a restraint on the decrement(TotalDaysOff-1) so that it does not produce a negative value. Cause that'll affect the result and might not perform as expected.

Comment: This will return the day the sick leave started, not the last day of sick leave.

Comment: no problem, but you may want to read above as Mark may want everyday of the week where sick days is more than one.

Answer (score 1):

based on my understanding, i tried to make this query, i hope his works and suit based on what you are looking for

```
SELECT T1.LEAVE_START_DAY, SUM(TOTAL_DAY_OFF) AS FREQUENCY
FROM
  (Select 
    DATENAME(DAY, START_DATE) AS LEAVE_START_DAY,
    TOTAL_DAY_OFF
  FROM TableLeave) T1
GROUP BY T1.LEAVE_START_DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

I put some random data into temp table to write this:

```
select CAST(v.startDate as datetime) startDate, CAST(v.duration as int) duration
into ##leave
from (values('2018-05-15','9'),('2018-03-21','10'),('2018-01-12','5'),('2017-12-24','1'),('2017-11-25','10'),('2017-11-09','2'),('2017-09-28','2'),('2017-07-29','2'),('2017-05-18','1'),('2017-02-24','9'),('2016-11-28','4'),('2016-08-27','4'))v(startDate,duration)
;
declare @maxLeaveLen integer = (select MAX(duration) from ##leave)
;
with ml as (
    select 1 n
    union all
    select n + 1 from ml
    where n + 1 <= @maxLeaveLen
), sd as ( 
    select DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(day, ml.n - 1, l.startDate)) [weekday]
    from ml ml
        cross join ##leave l
    where ml.n <= l.duration
) select sd.weekday, COUNT(1)
  from sd
  group by sd.weekday
```